# How to understand this graph problem related to bracket sequence?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, correctness-proof

This problem comes from a competitive programming problem. I'll restate it(feel free to see it [here](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1726/C)):

> A balanced bracket sequence is a bracket sequence(including open and
> close only) of even length such that we can add 1 and + to make it a
> valid mathematical expression. Given a balanced bracket sequence
> (BBS), we then construct a graph that has as many vertices as the
> length of the BBS. Vertex 1 correspond to first bracket, vertex 2
> correspond to second bracket, etc. An edge will only be formed between
> two vertices i and j iff substring from i to j of the BBS is again a
> BBS. Count the number of connected components of the constructed graph

My sumission: [sumission in C++](https://codeforces.com/contest/1726/submission/225997826)

My attempt to solve the problem was successful but I can't figure out how to prove my idea rigorously. Here's my idea:

Each pair-up in BBS can be assigned to a level. Say, this sequence "(())". Pair (1, 4) has level 1, pair (2, 3) has level 2. Or, this sequence "(()())()". Pair (1, 6) and pair (7, 8) has level 1; pair (2, 3) and pair (4, 5) has level 2.

My intuition is that all n-level pair-ups that is contained within a (n - 1)-level pair-ups should form a connected component - say, this simplest example: (()()()). Also, all other pair-ups should be separate from each other. So, the way to count is to pay attention to these contained, equal-level pair-ups (counting them all as 1) and discard when they're closed by close bracket. A stack should be suitable in this situation. Here's the psuedo code:

```
diff := 0 // use this spot levels
count := 0 // use this to answer
define an empty stack S

for each character ch in sequence: 
  if ch is ( then:
    diff += 1
  else:
    if !S.empty() and S.top() > diff then:
       while (!S.empty() && S.top() > diff): S.pop()

    if S.empty() or S.top() != diff then:
       S.push(diff);
       count += 1
            
    diff--;
Print count as answer
```

How to prove this algorithm rigorously? My attempt:

Firstly, I define rigorously what a BBS since it's vague to define BBS as stated above:

> A BBS is sequence where every its prefix contains more open brackets
> than close brackets

Secondly, I've tried to understand how the pair-up process works:

> Given positions of close brackets as t1 < t2 < t3 < ... < tn, we
> decide what pairs up with ti(1 <= i <= n) as follows:
>
> t1 pairs up with the closest open bracket
> t2 pairs up with the
> closest open bracket that does not pair up with t1
> t3 pairs up with
> the closest open bracket that does not pair up with t1, t2,
> ...
> ti
> pairs up with the closest open bracket that does not pair up with t1,
> ..., t(i-1).

I've checked and think this definition should partially help us to understand the situation a bit. But it struggles me to come up with "what is a level of a pair-up?". I'm stuck from here. So, my question:

1. How to proceed from here?
2. How to prove this algorithm rigorously?